# Javascript + HTML: Button Not Calling on Function Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have made a button:

```
<input type="button" value="a" onclick="searchLetter(this)"></input>
```

When clicked, it is supposed to call on a function which checks if the letter is in the `word` and if it is, add it to the `spaces` array in the corresponding spot:

```
    function searchLetter(obj)
    {
        var letter = obj.value;
        obj.disable;
        for (i = 0; i <= word.length; i++){
            if (word[i] == letter) {
                wordSpaces[i] = letter;
                document.getElementById('spaces').innerHTML = wordSpaces.join('');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the button is not calling on it and I am not sure why.

[Here is the JSFiddle (Hangman)](https://jsfiddle.net/JoshKono/3vdwLasc/1/)

Comment: check your console..`word` is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function pickWord() {
    var  word = dictionary[Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length)];
     var wordSpaces = [];
     for (var i = word.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     wordSpaces.push("_ ");
     document.getElementById('spaces').innerHTML = wordSpaces.join('');

 }
```

In your code, `word` and `wordSpaces` are a local variable to that function.

But in

```
 function searchLetter(obj) {
     var letter = obj.value;
     for (var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
```

you're trying to refer the `word` variable. That's why it's not entering the loop

So it must be like:

```
 var word, wordSpaces;
 function pickWord() {
     word = dictionary[Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length)];
     wordSpaces = [];
     for (var i = word.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     wordSpaces.push("_ ");
     document.getElementById('spaces').innerHTML = wordSpaces.join('');

 }
 function searchLetter(obj) {
     var letter = obj.value;
     for (var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
         if (word[i] == letter) {
             wordSpaces[i] = letter;
             document.getElementById('spaces').innerHTML = wordSpaces.join('');
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: ok that makes sense thanks! (have to wait 7 mins before i can select and answer)

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope issue. The `searchLetter` function is trying to access your `word` variable, but can't find it because it's in the other function and not within this function's scope.

One way to correct this is by declaring `word` in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is several errors in your code. You can use the console of your browser to see them (f12 opens it on all browsers, I think).

You have to declare the variables `word` and `wordSpaces` outside the `pickWord` function.

https://jsfiddle.net/gael/3vdwLasc/3/

You should also verify that the word has been initialized when you click on a letter.